# Using regex in R's grep to not match

Tags: r, regex

I have a dataframe `df` like shown below:

```
df <- data.frame(date=as.Date(c('2018-01-01', '2018-02-01', '2018-03-01')), 
  rate6M=rnorm(3), oldrate6M=rnorm(3), marketrate6M=rnorm(3),
  rate12M=rnorm(3), oldrate12M=rnorm(3), marketrate12M=rnorm(3))
```

I want to create a subset of `df` called `df6M` with `date` and the columns that end with `6M` EXCEPT for the columns that contain `oldrate` or `marketrate`. This subsets `df` in a way that includes `date` and all columns ending with `6M`:

```
df6M <- df[grep('date|6M$', names(df))]
```

How can I modify the above to explicitly exclude `oldrate` and `marketrate`?

P.S. Please don't say to do something like `df6M <- df[grep('date|^rate6M$', names(df))]`. I want to explicitly exclude certain columns because in reality I have a much bigger dataframe with many columns ending with `6M`.

Comment: Not sure, but `grep('^(?!.*(?:old|market)rate).*(?:date|6M$)', names(df), perl=TRUE)` should be what you ask for.

Comment: grepl() & !grepl()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than trying to do everything in one big regex, I'd just use two regexes with `grepl` and the usual logical operations:

```
df6m = df[grepl('date|6m$', names(df)) & !grepl('oldrate|marketrate', names(df))]
```

Answer (score 3):

I suppose this might do for you:

```
dont_want = grep('oldrate|marketrate', names(df))
want = grep('date|6M$', names(df))

df6M <- df[setdiff(want,dont_want)]
```